# Add custom .gitignore file to list of templates

Tags: github-enterprise

My organization hosts its own GitHub Enterprise instance. Is it possible to add a new .gitignore file to the list of templates when creating a new repository?

[image: Create a new repository with git ignore template]

Comment: I don't believe you can do that.... in their [GitHub ReST API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/gitignore) they only have the ability to pull from a known list which it looks like they get from [GitHub's public `github/gitignore` repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore).  Also in their [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/graphql/reference/mutations) docs I don't see a _mutation_ or _input object_ for GitIgnore.

Comment: I added a feedback item requesting this, as I'd love to have this feature as well. If you're interested in this please consider interacting on it. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/62107